# Best way to use OAuth for application

Tags: angularjs, authentication, laravel, oauth

I am building an AngularJS application with a Laravel API. I am looking for authentication for a couple of days, but I am stuck.

I found OAuth 2.0 as a kind of default authentication, also used by Facebook and Twitter and so more. A lot of tutorials I found are about using OAuth 2.0 with Facebook and Twitter or Google. But, I do not want to authenticatie a user with Facebook, but I want to build my own authentication, using the user credentials in my own database. So I guess, I need my own OAuth provider.

The authentication has to be very secure and easy to connect for other companies, who want to use our data (it is a web application for primary schools).

I believe there are a lot of answers possible on this question. But, I also believe a lot of people have the same question ;)

Who can explain me how to use OAuth 2.0 or a similar authentication method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right - if you want to implement OAuth 2.0 you need to be your own provider (or authorization server). Being your own provider also means you can actually skip some parts of the process (e.g. the screen with a confirmation if the user really wants to grant this application the right to that etc...)

If you decide to go with OAuth 2.0, there's a widely used package called [oauth2-server-laravel](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel) that helps with the whole process.

However you could also develop you're own token-based authentication system. Actually the basics are pretty simple:

1. Login
2. Verify credentials
3. Generate token
4. Store token in database

And then on request you check if the token is in the database (and hasn't expired yet)

Dead simple right? Well.. as you may already know, that's too easy to be true.
Especially where security is of high importance, You have to consider every case and you should really know what you're doing. That's why I recommend you use the OAuth standard. Yes, it may be a bit of an overkill but I believe it's worth it.

Hope I could help :)